# How to make a menu that has buttons to click?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

I'm making a UnitConverter program to convert various units, such as temperatures, weights, etc.

My design is to have a menu with the following buttons as Temperature Converter, Weight Converter, etc. However, I have tried using a menu, but I do not know how exactly. Can someone help me? Here is my code.

ALSO, important: do I have to have an activity and/or a xml file for each converter (temperature, weight)? If so, can you explain?

```
package com.sapra.unitconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BetterUnitConverterActivity extends Activity
{
    private EditText text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    // This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
    // "On Click property" of the button
    public void myClickHandler(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                if (text.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
            if (celsiusButton.isChecked())
            {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)) + " degrees celsius.");
                celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
            } 
            else
            {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)) + " degrees fahrenheit.");
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //WHAT DO I ADD HERE??- menu.add();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
       //IS ANY OF THIS RIGHT?
       switch (item.getItemId())
       {
            case R.id.temp:
                setContentView(R.layout.main); //MY QUESTION WAS HERE: SHOULD I CREATE A XML FILE NAMED TEMP AND THEN DO setContentView(R.layout.temp);?
                return true;
            case R.id.weight:
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    // Converts to celsius
    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }

    // Converts to fahrenheit
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
    }
}
```

This is what my mainmenu.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/temp" android:visible="true" android:enabled="
 android:title="Temperature Converter"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/weight" android:visible="true" android:enabled="
 android:title="Weight Converter"></item>
 </menu>
```

So, please, help me understand how to write a menu. Eventually, like I said, I would like to have (5) buttons on the main menu, each linking to a different type of converter (temperature, weight, length, etc.)

Comment: It seems as if you really haven't read much about developing Android applications. I would take a step back, and spend a lot of time reading first, and following some examples. I would take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html, then to the fundamentals, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html, then finally, go through some tutorials, http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, I actually have read many articles about developing Android applications. I appreciate you taking the time to provide links, however this does not help me exactly.

Comment: The link to Android Design is there so you'll rethink your design a bit. Using the menu system isn't a recommended practice for app navigation. I was hoping you'd look through the patterns section: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html

Comment: I have no idea about placing buttons on a menu. Can you use something else, like the RadioButton, or even a dialog rather than a menu?

Comment: @Christopher Perry: Sorry if I have not clarified, but I am making 1 app that can convert between various units. I want to have an organized way for the user to convert any unit they want. This is why I want a menu.

Answer (score 0):

What they are trying to explain to you is that a menu is not the best approach to doing what you want. Stop to read that page that @Christopher Perry mentioned, it gives excellent information on how to design good apps.

For instance, instead of using a menu, you can add buttons above your app, like in the contacts list, replacing the text for Temperature and Weight, or whatever you want:

[image: Image took from somewhere on internet. It's not mine]

Answering your question, on how to write a menu:

Your xml tells me that you want two buttons, so first you create your options menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();       
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then you add your code for your two options inside onPtionsItemSelected():

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.temp:
        //  Code Here...
        return true;
    case R.id.weight:
            //  Code Here...
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Plus, if you want you can use onPrepareOptionsMenu to enable/disable buttons as you need, a quick search gives you many tutorials about it. But I reinforce what Christopher said, this is not the best approach to navigate trough your app and you should not use it.